# Python: sys.exc_info() is missing local variables

Tags: python

In Python, I have code that catches an exception, like this:

```
try:
    <do stuff>
except:
    exc_info = sys.exc_info()
```

The problem I'm running into is that the traceback object (exc_info[2]) is non-deterministically missing local variables in the traceback objects. I know this for a fact because I run the exact same code and sometimes the variables are in tb.tb_frame.f_locals and sometimes not. The global variables are always correct in tb.tb_frame.f_globals.

What is populating the f_locals structure? What might cause that local variables dictionary to be empty sometimes?

Comment: It sounds like there must be some non-determinism in your code.  Threads?  Network I/O?  Anything?

Comment: I'd agree with Ned; tb_frame is really the frame of the calling code, and if the variable isn't there then it isn't set.  Well, note that re-raised exceptions keep their tb object, so maybe the frame isn't pointing to the scope you think it is?

Answer (score 0):

What is in the locals is completely dependent on the code in that local context.  For example:

```
if condition:
    foo='foo'
else:
    bar='bar'
```

if `condition==True` then `foo` will be in `locals()` and `bar` will not, otherwise `bar` will be in `locals()` and `foo` will not.